# How to save DOB from 3 dropdownlist (ASP.NET) into sql database?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have an ASP.NET form containing 3 dropdown lists. The lists are used to select a DOB (date of birth).  How do I save the selected date in a sql database? Do I need 3 separate columns for `DD`, `MM`, and  `YY`? If I need to create 3 columns, how would I calculate age? I use stored procedures to transfer values from the form to my database.

Please bear in mind that I am a beginner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You take the individual values (Mon, Day, Year), combine them in to a single date, and then store that. For display you do the reverse, you take the date, break it down in to the individual values, and then update each drop down appropriately.

Make sure you validate the date before storing it so you don't end up trying to store "Feb 30, 2012".

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following

- Create a date column in the database table

then do it like

```
int yr = 2009; //yrdropdown value
int month = 04; //monthdropdown value
int days = 30; //day dropdown value
DateTime dob = new DateTime(yr, month, day);
```